# How to call 'shapely' .coords on a fiona filtered list?

Tags: python, pyqgis, ogr, shapely, fiona

I have to filter a shapefile by attribute then compare it to another shapefile using .coords...however I am a bit perplexed how to do this as my filter is returning a list type...(and .coords requires a shapely Geometric object).

Is there another way to filter my shapefile and then get the coordinates of the filtered items?

```
import fiona
from shapely import Point
# open a shapefile of points 
with fiona.open("file.shp") as src:
   # returns a list - w all attributes and point geoms
   filter_list = filter(lambda f: f['properties']['foo']=='bar', src)
   # need to run .coords on filter_list
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you only want the point coordinates, you don't need Shapely, simply use the appropriate key of the dictionary:

```
for point in filter_list:
      print point['geometry']['coordinates']
(270977.604378, 153144.810665),...
```

If you want a Shapely geometry, use the [shape](http://toblerity.org/shapely/manual.html#python-geo-interface) function of Shapely:

```
from shapely.geometry import Point, shape
for point in filter_list:
     print shape(point['geometry'])
POINT (270977.604378 153144.810665),....
```

Comment: gene, do you know if the Shapely User Manual is available as a pdf somewhere?

Comment: no, but simply use the [Shapely User Manual](http://toblerity.org/shapely/manual.html)