# How to measure distance using shapely

Tags: python, pyqgis, ogr, shapely, fiona

Reading the [documentation](http://toblerity.org/shapely/manual.html)...it looks like I should have this right, but I don't.

The example is:

> Point(0,0).distance(Point(1,1))
>
> 1.4142135623730951

Based on this example I wrote this block (..note: update, 'capital' starts as a shapely obj, and city_pt is a dict...full of multipoints it appears, looking like this).

[{'geometry': {'type': 'MultiPoint', 
'coordinates': [(4942585.391221348,  #3940520.723517349)]}, 
'type': 'Feature', 'id': '17', 'properties': 
OrderedDict([(u'Status', u'Bad')])}]

```
    # capital = shapely obj
    capital_pt = capital.coords
    # city_point is a dict ... multipoints
    for city_point in filtered_all:
        city_items = shape(city_point['geometry'])
        # capital_pt = POINT (13531245.47570414 2886003.268927813) 
        # city_items[0] = POINT (4942585.391221348 3940520.723517349)

        # measure distance

        # calculate the distance between capital and cities
        distance_between_pts = capital_pt.distance(city_point)
```

and got this:

> > AttributeError: 'CoordinateSequence' object has no attribute 'distance'

trying the om_henners answer I get

> > AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'coords'

Just in terminal I tried this:

> > > x = POINT (13531245.47570414 2886003.268927813).distance(POINT (4942585.391221348 3940520.723517349))
> > >
> > > File "", line 1
> > >           x = POINT (13531245.47570414 2886003.268927813).distance(POINT (4942585.391221348 3940520.723517349))
> > >                                                        ^
> > >       SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `capital_pt` is the `coords` attribute of the original `capital` shapely geometry object. In itself this is not a shapely geometry, rather a sequence of tuples of flots which are the point objects. Instead you should be using

```python
distance_between_pts = capital.distance(city_items)
```

Given your case where you're trying to calculate distances for all points in a dataset opened by fiona, a quick example might help also:

```python
import fiona
import shapely.geometry

# capital is a shapely geometry object

with fiona.open(path_to_data) as src:
    for feature in src:
        geom = shapely.geometry.shape(feature["geometry"])
        distance_between_pts = capital.distance(geom)
        print(distance_between_pts)
```

Comment: city_point is a dict. So that's basically:                <class 'shapely.geometry.point.Point'> # capital
<type 'dict'> # city_point

Comment: Could this be a problem?...it appears I have MultiPoints (and capital is a Point). [{'geometry': {'type': 'MultiPoint', 'coordinates': [(4942585.391221348, 3940520.723517349)]}, 'type': 'Feature', 'id': '17', 'properties': OrderedDict([(u'Status', u'Bad')])}]

Comment: @user14696 Updated my answer to reference `city_items` instead of `city_point`. Basically you want to use distance between two shapely geometries. And no, since there's only a single point in your MultiPoint geometry it should work fine for distance calculations.

Comment: good to know the multipoint is okay...but still running into road blocks. AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'coords'. distance_between_pts = capital.distance(city_items.coords) gives me the '    "Multi-part geometries do not provide a coordinate sequence")
NotImplementedError: Multi-part geometries do not provide a coordinate sequence'.

Comment: It should just be between the two shapely geometries, i.e. `distance_between_pts = capital.distance(city_items)` where both `capital` and `city_items` are shapely geometry objects. Ignore the `coords` attribute :)

Comment: thanks. city_items is actually a dict. I'll try some research on those points you make. See if I can get the city_items to be shapely geoms (again...I guess the filtering I did with fiona made them into dictionaries).

Comment: @user14696 Sorry, from your code it looked like you were using the `shapely.geometry.shape` method to cast the `city_point` dict (which contains a `geometry` element) to a shapely geometry as `city_items`

Comment: @user14696 I've also added a quick code snippet which will hopefully help with the reading of the data from fiona and calculating the distances.

Answer (score 1):

`POINT (13531245.47570414 2886003.268927813)` is not a Shapely object but the  [WKT](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-known_text) 
format of a Point

A point in Shapely is :

```
point1 =  Point(13531245.47570414,2886003.268927813)
type(point1)
<class 'shapely.geometry.point.Point'>
```

The WKT representation of the point is:

```
# WKT
print point1.wkt
POINT (13531245.47570414 2886003.268927813)
type(point1.wkt)
<type 'str'>
```

So, the correct formulation is `Shapely_geometry.dist(Shapely_geometry)` and not `str.distance(str)`:

```
x = Point(13531245.47570414,2886003.268927813).distance(Point(4942585.391221348,3940520.723517349))
print x
8653154.86449
```

If you want to use the coordinates from the result of Fiona (without Shapely, your question [How to call 'shapely' .coords on a fiona filtered list?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/139905/how-to-call-shapely-coords-on-a-fiona-filtered-list))

```
import math # or numpy
def euclidean_distance( l1,l2):
    return math.sqrt((l2[0]-l1[0])**2 + (l2[1]-l1[1])**2)
 print euclidean_distance((13531245.47570414,2886003.268927813),(4942585.391221348,3940520.723517349))   
8653154.864488555
```