# Errors relating to merging point shapefiles

Tags: python, point, shapely, fiona, pyproj

I have created two different point shapefiles which represent towns within a state. However I want to know the distance between both towns, but first I want to draw a line between them. Is this possible or should I merge both shapefiles together first?

I was trying to merge the point shapefiles together as one but I experienced an error.

> TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

```
vicksent = ".vick.shp"
towncent= ".town.shp"

from shapely.geometry import MultiPoint, point, shape, mapping

schema = {'geometry': 'Point',
         'properties': {}, }
with fiona.open('mew.shp', 'w', 'ESRI Shapefile', schema,     crs=from_epsg(29900)) as output:
   prop = {}
   centriod1= vicksent
   centriod2 = towncent
   output.write([centriod1,{'geometry': point, 'properties': prop}])
   output.write([centriod2, {'geometry': point, 'properties': prop}])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont need to merge or create a line between them to measure distance:

```
import fiona, shapely.geometry

p1 = '/home/bera/GIS/Data/testdata/p1.shp'
p2 = '/home/bera/GIS/Data/testdata/p2.shp'

#https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/140069/how-to-measure-distance-using-shapely
firstpoint = [shapely.geometry.shape(f['geometry']) for f in fiona.open(p1)][0]
secondpoint = [shapely.geometry.shape(f['geometry']) for f in fiona.open(p2)][0]

print(firstpoint.distance(secondpoint))
```

Im assuming you only have one point in each shapefile.

Comment: yes, i only have one point in each shapefile

Comment: but if i was to create a line between them, how willl i go with that if you dont mind me asking

Comment: That is a different question than what you have posted

Comment: its just i have been having difficulty for more than 3 hours trying to draw the line between two different point shapefile and time is not on my side, so please any little idea would be appreciated

Comment: Stop thinking about them as shapefiles, they are points once you have read them in.

Comment: i even created a a dictionary to store the points form both point files and tried to outpt them into a new shapefile using fiona but it did not work. got an error saying "must be real number, not dict".i am just confused.