# Measure distance between points in python

Tags: python, shapely, fiona

I am trying to determine a rough distance between points in my shapefile.

The shapefile I am working with has 28 million points in the structure `x y z`.
I am hoping to find the most common distance between each pair of points in metres.

I have come across this post [How to measure distance using shapely](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/140069/how-to-measure-distance-using-shapely)  which uses the code structure

```
import fiona
import shapely.geometry

# capital is a shapely geometry object

with fiona.open(path_to_data) as src:
    for feature in src:
        geom = shapely.geometry.shape(feature["geometry"])
        distance_between_pts = capital.distance(geom)
        print(distance_between_pts)
```

Whilst this example is comparing the distance between cities and capitals (2 different things), I'm wondering is there a way I can use `fiona` and `shapely` to give me the distance between points within 1 shapefile?

Yes I know 28 million calculations is a large magnitude. But if I could even limit the calculations to a much smaller number of points and just take a rough distance as my calculation

Comment: (28M*28M)/2 is a lot of distance calculations

Comment: Between each pair of point ? Do you have that powerful machine ? Wow

Comment: @IanTurton I know ... Is there even a way to limit the calculation to the first 100 or so and I can take a rough calculation?

Comment: I guess that you want to get that information to support the bathymetry challenge of rasterizing a depth point data set that appears in your other questions. But maybe an effective method for estimating the distances and also for getting a visual image of distribution could be to take another raster route and create a kernel density map like here https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/kernel-density.htm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with `itertools.combinations()`. In your case:

```
import fiona
import shapely.geometry
import itertools

with fiona.open(path_to_data) as src:
    for feat_1, feat_2 in itertools.combinations(src, 2):
        geom_1 = shapely.geometry.shape(feat_1["geometry"])
        geom_2 = shapely.geometry.shape(feat_2["geometry"])
        distance_between_pts = geom_1.distance(geom_2)
        print(distance_between_pts)
```

What `itertools.combinations(src, 2)` does is that, given some iterator (in this case `src`), it returns all combinations of the features in the iterator that have length `2`.

Comment: Fantastic! Thank you!! Quick question - is there any way to limit the number of geometries it searches for?? (to save time)

Comment: `for i, (feat_1, feat_2) in enumerate(itertools.combinations(src, 2)):` ... `if i > 999: break`.  But unless you also randomize the results may be influenced by the order they appear in the data source

Comment: The way I would do it is first sample randomly a number of points from your data. And then compute the distances between them live above. This way, the results won't be influenced by the order they appear in the file

Comment: Also I would try sample different number of points and compare the results. If for example the results you get when sampling 1k, 10k and 50k points are very similar, then it's probably a pretty good estimate of the real value you'd get if using all points